# Updating a sharepoint 2003 list with user data provided in Nintex workflow

Tags: sharepoint-workflow, workflow-activity, nintex-workflow, sharepoint-2003

Apologies for the naivety of the question, but I am brand new to using Nintex workflow in Sharepoint.

Having not found examples in the Nintex manuals or online, the simple task I wish to perform is to send a task to a user(s) to prompt them to update a specific field in the Sharepoint list.

I have created a workflow that assigns a task to a user when a new entry is created in a list. However, the "missing link" is that I cannot find how to present the list field to the user within the task such that they may simply update the existing field. e.g. Having created a new "client" entry in a list, I wish various people to populate fields on the records.

Creating a separate form per field I wish to be updated seems long-winded and within Nintex 2007 I am struggling to see how I incorporate existing field from the data list on which I am running the workflow.

Links or tips gratefully received.